Anylogic : how to connect an agent to a place?
In my simulation, I'm generating 30 agents/minute, that are moved to a specified node in the model.

In theory, they are supposed to go each one in a different node. In reality, sometimes they enter the same node at the same time.
How can I make it so when an agent is generated, it will be linked to a node that is not yet linked ?
this is the seize logic ; the resource sets is Places_disponible:

Here is the logic used in the nodes

Here is the Places_disponible resourcepool, which is static and its capacity is defined directly

you can see here that the agents go inside other locations even if they're connected to 1 already
here is the function

sorry, not sure what the issue is. Can you boil it down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Sure, i edited the topic into the minimal example

Still too confusing. Here is a good example of a well-formatted question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78516068/add-new-parameters-from-simulation-to-initial-database-in-anylogic  . Pls make our lives easy :)

I tried to make it simpler, I hope it's not confusing anymore

well, I formatted it for you so pics are visible :)

Network nodes do not have a concept of "filled" or "available". They are purely 2D coordinates that can have a million agents on top of each other or none. They care not one bit :)
You need to create a custom agent type that acts as a resource, keeping track of a specific "node" being busy or not. You can give it a parameter of type Node to link to some space, but do not have to.

That's what i tried to do with the Places_disponible resourcepool. It works with the custom agent type "Positions" which i place in every positions, and then i tried to connect the agents in the nodes with the agents that are generated. I don't understand how to make it so the agents generated go to the node they're connected to though

Well, show how you setup the agents, both MyAgent and Position. Again, try to simplify for us: 1 MyAgent trying to move to 1 Position agent. How is it defined, how does it fail? Pls either edit this question or open a new one. Make sure screens are visible directly, also highlight the important parts of the screens... (Again: highest prio must be to make our lives easy :) Ideally I can reply with 1 word after reading a good question that takes less than 60 sec to read... If this is too hard, simplify the question and core problem

The movement of MyAgent is setup by the moveto blocks. the first movement is to a node where it will enter a seize block to be assigned to a position. But, to go in these positions, it enters an outputin block, and is sent to one of the 6 outputout blocks (by probabilities, each block has an equal probability). That's the thing i want to change, i need to make it so they don't chose a positions based on probabilities, but on the connection they have. (i added an image where you can see the issue. sorry i can't display it fully i can only use the links)

i tried to use a function to verify the connected agents , but i don't get it to work right. i also added the image of that function

Again, this is worth a new question. SOF comments are not useful to give more details, SOF is a Q&A place, not a forum :) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
