Add new parameters from simulation to initial database in Anylogic
In my Anylogic simulation I'm creating new agents by a schedule in my database.

There are parameters (empty columns in DB) which will be calculated for each agent during simulation.


Is there a way to add these parameters for each created agent to the initial database?
Many thanks for your help.
Kevin

hey, pls stick to 1 question only, feel free to open several questions. Also, really not clear on all 3 questions here. What do you have, what do you want and what have you tried? Also, add some screens to help us help you. Make our lives easy, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow . Happy to help :)

I tried to adjust my question for better understanding.

much better, thx


There are parameters (empty columns in DB) which will be calculated for each agent during simulation.

Bad practice. Whatever is calculated at runtime should be stored in variables. Parameters are used to define agents, not their results. Ok to have empty result columns in dbase, though...

Is there a way to add these parameters for each created agent to the initial database?

If you mean to write agent performance results to the dbase, use the [update][1](...) function to write into your dbase. Lookup your agent via a unique id column (that the agent should store as a parameter on creation, yes).

Ok, I think that your solution with the update function and the unique id is exactly that what I need. But my programming skills are not good enough to implement it.

First: pls upvote a reply if it was helpful. Second: Either have a go yourself with the help and example models (it is all there for you). Or open a new "how to" question in LinkedIn. Or a specific "why is X not working" tech question here on SOF, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community
